# Изменение цвета иконки внутри кластера

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Есть Яндекс-карта с объектами, созданными через objectManager. Кластеризация включена. Как изменить цвет иконки при клике?

Этот код меняет вообще иконки на карте:

```
myMap.geoObjects.events.add('click', function (e) {
    e.get('target').options.set('preset', 'islands#redIcon');
});
```

Не понимаю, как поменять цвет только одной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации API Яндекс.Карт есть почти точно описывающий вашу задачу [пример](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_events).

Разве что вам нужна реакция уже на клик. Но изменение функции при этом минимальное — нужно лишь прослушивать другое событие:

```
objectManager.objects.events.add('click', function (e) {
    var objectId = e.get('objectId');
    objectManager.objects.setObjectOptions(objectId, {
        preset: 'islands#redIcon'
    });
});
```